# Install Label Studio in Google Cloud and make it available with the public IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, server, virtual-machine

I have a VM instance in Google Cloud with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I set it to allow HTTP traffic.

I need to setup Label Studio (https://github.com/heartexlabs/label-studio) in this VM so anyone can access it by just typing the VM public IP.

I already tried building it with docker:

```
sudo docker build -t heartexlabs/label-studio:latest .
```

But when i run it with:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 heartexlabs/label-studio:latest
```

It doesn't work, wheres the output of the container list

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                             COMMAND            CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
2e728edbe6d5   heartexlabs/label-studio:latest   "./tools/run.sh"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 8080/tcp   gracious_shamir
```

I also tried to install it with pip and run it with:

```
label-studio start --host 34.66.116.52 --port 80 testproject
```

If anyone has experience with Google Cloud VM and can help set this up with docker or with a WSGI server I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
`` sudo docker run --rm -d -p 80:8080 -v `pwd`/my_project:/label-studio/my_project --name label-studio heartexlabs/label-studio:latest label-studio start my_project --init ``
I was able to access it from External IP with this.

Comment: Thank you so much! it work perfectly, do you have some insight so I can understand how it woks? `-p 80:8080` this part in particular

Comment: Flag ```-p``` publishes container to the network, then it's ```host port : container port```.