# Docker on Google Compute Engine can't access port 80 despite setting firewall rules

Tags: django, docker, nginx, google-compute-engine, devops

I have a container running Django, Nginx, and Gunicorn running on Compute Engine

I can successfully deploy and SSH into the VM but cannot access the external URL to the container despite creating several firewall rules.

It seems to be closed to port 80 even after exposing it from within the VM.

how do I fix this?

Here's a copy of my:

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services: 
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: app-name:prod
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles 
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    command: gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5432

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  pgdata:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

NGINX conf:

```
upstream core {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://core;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/mediafiles/;
    }

}
```

Dockerfile:

```
##################################
# THIS IS A MULTI-STAGE BUILD TO #
# REDUCE THE SIZE OF THE IMAGE.  #
##################################

# BUILDER

FROM python:3.9.2-alpine3.12 as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc musl-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install flake8
COPY . .
RUN flake8 --ignore=E501,F401 .

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt


# FINAL

FROM python:3.9.2-alpine3.12

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app

ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/mediafiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

RUN apk update && apk add libpq
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh $APP_HOME

COPY . $APP_HOME

RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

USER app
```

NGINX Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Here's a similar step I followed in setting up the VM: [Why is Google Compute Engine not running my container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60965622/why-is-google-compute-engine-not-running-my-container)

Here's the error I get when I try to access port 80: **`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.XXX.XX.XXX port 80: Connection refused`**

**edit:** Added both app Dockerfile and NGINX Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error you are getting may be a caused by a firewall rule blocking traffic or the container is not listening on port 80.**

To be sure [create](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall#creating_a_firewall_ingress_rule) a new firewall rule explicitly allowing connections to this host on port 80;

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-http --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:80 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=http-server
Creating firewall...⠹
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/qqqq/global/firewalls/default-allow-http].                   
Creating firewall...done.                                                                                                                            
NAME                NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW   DENY  DISABLED
default-allow-http  default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80        False
```

Just make sure your host VM has a `http-server` [network-tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) attached.

Then check if the port is open using nmap:

```
$ nmap -Pn ip.to.check.xxx
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-16 12:04 CEST
PORT   STATE SERVICE
...
80/tcp open  http
```

If you see `80/tcp open  http` then it means the port is open and an app is listening on it. If it's not and the firewall rule is active then you have to look at your container nginx configuration. If you provide more details (dockerfile) to reproduce your issue it may be possible to troubleshoot this further.

Also - if you're running your container manually (not using Container Optimised OS) then [have a look at this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640651/12257250) which may be helpful to you.

**---- U P D A T E ----- This actually helped:**

Change ports in the nginx service in the compose file; instead of having - 1337:80 try the other way: - 80:1337.

According the [Docker networking docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) the values should be the other way around.

Comment: Thanks @Wojtek_B, I have updated the question with both Dockerfiles. I followed both steps and used tags but still didn't work.

Comment: You may try to change ports in the `nginx` service in the `compose` file; instead of having `- 1337:80` try the other way: `- 80:1337`. I've looked at the [Docker networking docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) and this is the only thing that I could find.